# GitHub Continues Integration C# Windows

Tags: c#, windows, git, github, continuous-integration

I'm just starting my Exam project at my school. Studying Systems Development with C#.

We're using GitHub as our online repository, and it just recommended to set up "Continues Integration". I looked at it, and the idea seemed nice. Our course is based around Test Driven Development, so we already have tests in place.

I first looked at Travis, unfortunatly, I cannot figure out how to get this to work with Windows, nor Unit Tests.

Question is, is there a tool we can use to acheive continues integration with C# for windows platforms, for free?

Comment: [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/download/) has Windows downloads.

Comment: Also have look at [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "continuous" integration, and yes, it is a good idea to learn about it.

Unfortunately, the question is too broad to answer directly. There are many solutions to get a working CI running, both locally and in the cloud; both for free and not-so-free.

It is, for a hobby/uni project,  also perfectly possible to roll your own, with a few cron jobs or commit hooks.

CI simply means that your test/build scripts are running automatically, ideally after each commit and for each separate branch, so you get early warning for bugs creeping in. The more  expensive or complex systems just add a loaf of customizability, reports, history, notifications etc. on top.

I would suggest googling a bit more. You really should be able to find something including documentation on how to use it. Wikipedia should have a handy table which you can filter down on "free" and "windows".